# Should curse words / swearing be acted upon in ways other than editing?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, users

I just noticed some bad language in a question on Stack Overflow:

[image: "But what are the fucking mistakes?"]

Of course, I could easily edit it out, but then I thought maybe users who use insulting language have to be reported to the higher up admins?

Comment: Always start with an edit. Only when they revert it or edit it back in it is early enough to raise a mod flag. And by following that advice there is also easy evidence for the mod to check out.

Comment: Unless the post is entirely an unsalvageable sweary rant, in which case flag it as rude/abusive.

Comment: I generally agree with editing out swear words as long as they are not directly targeting a user or group of users. In that case I would flag rude/abusive or for moderator attention no matter if I could have removed it.

Comment: If it had said "bloody", would you have reacted the same? You should because the intention is pretty much the same, add a little crudeness to the statement to stress it. Different cultures, different paths to the same goal.

Comment: Who is it insulting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the post can survive without the swear word, edit it out.

If the post contains a string of swear words, then chances are high that it's some kind of rant as opposed to an actual question, so close those.

Assume no ill intent in someone using profanity on the site.  They may be expressing their frustration with some <s>bullhockey</s> boolean variable they have to update, and they're at their wit's end with it.