# What to do about a question primarily in English, but with some rude content in another language?

Tags: discussion, flags, rude-or-abusive

A week ago, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703502/writing-in-excel-if-regex-condition-is-satisfied). It contains Russian word and Cyrillic, so I assume the author knows the Russian language.

Also, the post contains a couple of transliterated (п -> p, и -> i) Russian swear words.

Be it an answer, I would submit an edit request replacing mentioned words, or even pass by. By I don't see any reason to save question containing rudeness for no apparent cause. So I flagged the post as "Rude or abusive".

Flag was declined, and I want to know if possible:

- Was I wrong here and shouldn't flag such questions? Or should I raise a flag requiring moderators intervention in that case?
- What exactly could I do if I still believe the post is rude? (Not in this exact case, but in general)
- Are there any more precise guidelines on what is counted as rude?
- And is there a difference in "acceptable level" of rudeness in questions and answers?

Comment: If the post is offensive in a way that English-speaking readers might not recognise, you can mod-flag it and explain the problem.

Comment: While generally true, for single instances of relatively harmless words in an otherwise legitimate question, editing is the correct thing to do. Quoting a rejection reason we have, it isn't irredeemably rude, and should be edited instead

Comment: Side note: both words are roughly equivalent to "bitch" in both meaning and level of "swear-ness"... Use your own judgement if to flag that or just edit out (as suggested by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419735/should-curse-words-swearing-be-acted-upon-in-ways-other-than-editing)

Comment: Rudeness needs to be directed at someone, like "you are a b****!". This reads like it was just text containing words which *could* be used in such a way, but weren't. That makes it crass and unprofessional, not rude. The kind of language I hear around me daily, unfortunately. Coming out of the mouths of people of any age.